# Debian won't book on MacBook Pro

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, unix

I erased the entire content of my MacBook Pro when installing debian. Now, the laptop will not boot into Linux.

When I insert USB again it will start installation again. I even selected bootable flag on the partition but still will not boot.

The issue is that I do not have Mac OS either to go back...

Do you have suggestions what to do?

Comment: without asking why did you not create a bootable osx on USB did you read this https://wiki.debian.org/MacBookPro

Answer (score 2):

press cmd + R for internet recovery